# Ogre dotScene saving

Tags: c++, ogre3d, ogre, scene

I'm making a video game using Ogre3d. I load the .scene file with the most recent tinyxml dotscene loader. Now I want to save the modified scene back to the .scene file. Can someone give me an example or an hint on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to code the exact reverse process:

1. Loop over all relevant scene objects and for each one add the needed TiXmlElements to a TiXmlDocument.
2. At the end, save out the TiXmlDocument.

This [TinyXml Tutorial](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html) shows the needed code parts in terms of XML generation.

A real-world example is Ogitor (an WYSIWYG Ogre editor), where each editor object has [a method TiXmlElement* CXXXEditor::exportDotScene(TiXmlElement *pParent)](https://bitbucket.org/jacmoe/ogitor/src/2495109e50fc/Ogitor/src/EntityEditor.cpp?at=default#cl-290) that moves all relevant attributes/states into the TinyXml structures before it then gets saved into a file.